# Lindeloff bound on average for Hecke Maass L functions

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I have heard that a Lindeloff-type bound for Hecke Maass form L functions exist on average. However, I am unable to find it in literature nor understand the precise statement. Is it something like $$\frac{1}{M}\sum\limits_{T \leq t_j \leq T+M} \frac{L(u_j,1/2+it)}{|| u_j ||^2 \cosh \pi t_j} \ll (1+t_j+|t|)^{\epsilon}\ \ \quad ?$$

Also, what is the precise summand in that result? Is it $\left| \frac{L(u_j,1/2+it)}{|| u_j ||^2 \cosh \pi t_j}\right|$ or the second moment $\left| \frac{L(u_j,1/2+it)}{|| u_j ||^2 \cosh \pi t_j}\right|^2$ by any chance? Please mention the relevant reference and kindly specify how the Lindeloff follows from that reference theorem or Corollary?

Here u_j is an orthogonal basis for the space of Maass Cusp forms of weight 0 with respect to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and $t_j=\sqrt{\lambda_j-1/4}$ is the spectral parameter of $u_j$ and $\lambda_j$ is $u_j$-s Hyperbolic Laplacian eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the generalised Lindelöf hypothesis states that
$$L\left(\frac{1}{2} + it,f\right) \ll_{\varepsilon} ((1 + |t_f + t|)(1 + |t_f - t|))^{\varepsilon}$$
for $f \in \mathcal{B}_0$, where $\mathcal{B}_0$ denotes an orthonormal basis of Hecke-Maass cusp forms of weight $0$, level $1$; here $t_f$ denotes the spectral parameter of $f$. Since the Weyl law states that
$$\#\{f \in \mathcal{B}_0 : T - U \leq t_f \leq T + U\} \asymp TU$$
for $T^{\varepsilon} \leq U \leq T$ (more precisely, this is asymptotic to a constant multiple of $TU$), a Lindelöf-on-average bound for the $k$-th moment of $L(1/2 + it,f)$ would be something of the form
$$\sum_{\substack{f \in \mathcal{B}_0 \\ T - U \leq t_f \leq T + U}} \frac{\left|L\left(\frac{1}{2} + it,f\right)\right|^k}{L(1,\operatorname{ad}f)} \ll_{k,\varepsilon} TU ((1 + |T + t|)(1 + |T - t|))^{\varepsilon},$$
as this is the bound we would get simply by bounding each term individually assuming the generalised Lindelöf hypothesis and then summing over these bounds using the Weyl law.

As an aside, we note that $L(1,\operatorname{ad}f)$ is a special value of an $L$-function that is positive and satisfies the bounds $t_f^{-\varepsilon} \ll_{\varepsilon} L(1,\operatorname{ad}f) \ll_{\varepsilon} t_f^{\varepsilon}$ and is such that
$$\int_{\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}} |f(z)|^2 \, \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2} = \frac{2 |\rho_f(1)|^2 L(1,\operatorname{ad}f)}{\cosh \pi t_f}$$
with $\rho_f(1)$ the first Fourier-Whittaker coefficient of $f$, so that
$$f(z) = \sum_{\substack{n = -\infty \\ n \neq 0}}^{\infty} \rho_f(n) W_{0,it_f}(4\pi|n|y) e(nx).$$

In general (without any conditions on $k,t,U$), a Lindelöf-on-average bound for the $k$-th moment of $L(1/2 + it,f)$ is not known. However, many special cases are known.

---

If $k = 2$, then we can use the approximate functional equation (Theorem 5.3 of Iwaniec-Kowalski) to roughly write
$$L\left(\frac{1}{2} + it,f\right) \approx \sum_{n \leq ((1 + |t_f + t|)(1 + |t_f - t|))^{1/2}} \frac{\lambda_f(n)}{n^{\frac{1}{2} + it}}.$$
From here, the spectral large sieve (due to Deshouillers and Iwaniec; see this paper for a general version: https://doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.887) implies that if $|t| \leq TU$, then
$$\sum_{\substack{f \in \mathcal{B}_0 \\ T - U \leq t_f \leq T + U}} \frac{\left|L\left(\frac{1}{2} + it,f\right)\right|^2}{L(1,\operatorname{ad}f)} \ll_{\varepsilon} TU ((1 + |T + t|)(1 + |T - t|))^{\varepsilon},$$
as desired. However, if $|t| \geq (TU)^{1 + \delta}$ for some $\delta > 0$, then this no longer holds (the length of the Dirichlet polynomial is too long).

---

Similarly, if $k = 4$, then one can use the approximate functional equation for $|L(1/2 + it,f)|^2$ to see that if $|t| \leq T$, then
$$\sum_{\substack{f \in \mathcal{B}_0 \\ 0 \leq t_f \leq T}} \frac{\left|L\left(\frac{1}{2} + it,f\right)\right|^4}{L(1,\operatorname{ad}f)} \ll_{\varepsilon} T^{2 + \varepsilon}.$$
This method does not give strong enough bounds if $U \leq T^{1 - \delta}$ for some $\delta > 0$ or if $|t| \geq T^{1 + \delta}$ for some $\delta > 0$, however.

---

Improving the former result for $|t|$ large or the latter result for either $|t|$ large or $U$ small is difficult, but is known in certain cases. It is much harder than simply using approximate functional equations and the spectral large sieve. Some good references for this are these papers:

https://doi.org/10.2298/PIM0476041J

https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02588051

---

Finally, there are also bounds for integral moments in the $t$-aspect rather than discrete moments in the $t_f$-aspect. One can investigate the $k$-th integral moment
$$\int_{T - U}^{T + U} \left|L\left(\frac{1}{2} + it,f\right)\right|^k \, dt,$$
where $T^{\varepsilon} \leq U \leq T$. A Lindelöf-on-average bound for this would be something of the form $O_{k,\varepsilon}(U ((1 + |T + t_f|)(1 + |T - t_f|))^{\varepsilon})$.

For $k = 2$, one can use approximate functional equations together with the Montgomery-Vaughan mean value estimate (i.e. Gallagher's large sieve) to obtain this bound so long as $U = T$ and $t_f \leq T$. In other ranges, this is a hard problem, but modern methods can obtain results in certain ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am checking one by one. In particular, I am interested in the result pertaining to $k=2$. In particular, I was trying to prove the Lindelof kind of bound that you produced in that case.  What I dont understand is how you could obtain the power 1/2 in $n \leq [(1+|t_f+t)(1+|t_f-t|)]^{1/2}$ in the approximate functional equation of L(1/2+it,f). I have been trying a lot and at best, I am getting $n \leq (1+|t_f+t)(1+|t_f-t|)$. And this prevents me from getting $(UT)^{1+\epsilon}$ that you produced. At best, I am getting $(UT)^{2+\epsilon}$ when $|t| \leq UT$.

Comment: For simplicity, I am using Theorem 1.1 in the paper of Jutila.                                           
 M. Jutila, On spectral large sieve inequalities, Functiones et Approximatio 28, (2000), 7–18.

Comment: The analytic conductor of $L(1/2+it,f)$ is $\mathfrak{q}=(1+|t_f+t|)(1+|t_f-t|)$. The approximate functional equation states that
$$L\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)=\sum_{\pm}\epsilon_f^{\frac{1\mp 1}{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_f(n)}{n^{\frac{1}{2}\pm it}} V_{\frac{1}{2}\pm it}(n),$$
where $V_{1/2\pm it}(n)$ is $1 + O((n/\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}})^{-1/6})$ if $n \leq \sqrt{\mathfrak{q}}$ and is $\ll_A (1 + n/\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}})^{-A}$ for any $A > 0$ if $n \geq \sqrt{\mathfrak{q}}$. See Theorem 5.3 and Proposition 5.4 of Iwaniec-Kowalski.

Comment: Thank you for the generous answer. May I know if similar Lindelof on average bounds exist in the level 1 case in terms of weight k for averages of holomorphic Hecke cusp eigenforms? Also if I consider level aspect, could you tell me whether the Lindelof is known? Could you share references, i any?

Comment: But there are $\asymp k$ Hecke forms in each $\mathcal{H}_k$. In total, we have $\asymp Gk \asymp GK$ forms. So $\frac{ (KG)^{1+\epsilon} }{KG} = (KG)^{\epsilon}$ Is this the Lindeloff on average bound here? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: (2/3) I mean from the Theorem 2.1 in doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.887, it follows that (the inner sum in that paper is from $n=N$ to $2N$, but I believe I can make it from 1 to $2N$ by adding an extra $\log 2N$ on the right hand side) $\sum\limits_{K \leq k \leq K+G} \sum\limits_{f \in \mathcal{H}_k} \lvert L(1/2+it,f) \rvert^2 \ll_{\epsilon}(KG)^{1+\epsilon}$ provided $|t| \leq KG$. Read the last three comments in the order 1,3,2.

Comment: Yes, the same results hold for holomorphic modular forms of weight $k \in [T - U,T + U]$  since the spectral large sieve holds in the exact same setting. For level $q$ automorphic forms, you only get Lindelof on average by considering the fourth moment.